Magento DB Downgrade 2.4.3 EE to 2.4.6 CE
I am downgrading Magento 2.4.3 Enterprise edition to 2.4.6 community edition. While downgrading I am following few already available modules and blogs like below
https://github.com/opengento/magento2-downgrade-ee-ce/tree/master/scripts
Getting this below SQL error while downgrade
////
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1833 Cannot change column 'increment_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'magento_db/LCSVENROLMNTORDERPAYMENT_ORDERINCREMENTID_SALESORDER_INCREMENTID' of table 'magento_db/lc_services_enrollment_order_payment', query was: ALTER TABLE sales_order MODIFY COLUMN increment_id varchar(50) NULL  COMMENT "Increment ID", MODIFY COLUMN original_increment_id varchar(50) NULL  COMMENT "Original Increment ID"
////
